# Launch receiver app with parameter in google cast SDK 2.0?

Tags: google-cast

Is that possible to launch receiver app with a POST or GET parameter in google cast SDK 2.0?
I knew it's possible in sdk 1.0, but can't find it in sdk 2.0.

Here is what I want:

I would like to launch a receiver app but the IP address of the receiver app is changed time to time. (My receiver app is put on a RaspberryPi)
So, I would like to put a generic receiver app on public&fixed url as a http redirector.
something like  https://mypublic.receiver.url/?REALIP=x.x.x.x

The redirector will redirect chromecast device to launch http://x.x.x.x  and that should work.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Kevin Kuei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch parameters in the shape of query parameters are not supported any more. In your case, you can achieve the same with a bit more work: as you did, use a fixed url for your receiver and after launching the app, immediately send an out-of-bound message to the receiver with the new URL. Then have your receiver interpret that URL as whatever is appropriate for your case, for example include an iframe in your fixed receiver and load the url in that iframe, etc.